# Как составить плавную кривую из множества заданных точек?

Tags: математика, геометрия

Есть точки, неважно случайные они или заданные, необходимо соединить их так чтобы получилась плавная единая кривая. Думаю о кривых безье.

Comment: Порядок точек задан?

Comment: Если да, то например https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline

Comment: В Безье вам надо будет придумать как задавать направления. Или не все точки будут равноправными.

Comment: Порядок точек известен по ходу массива. Есть начало и конец.

Comment: В безье опорные точки, можно точно сказать что первая и последняя опорные точки принадлежат кривой, придется придумывать недостоющие опорные точки. Т.е. если множество разбить на пары точек последовательно.

Comment: Я затрудняюсь, вопрос большой. Много деталей.

Comment: Если разбить множество точек на пары таким образом, что 1 и 2, 2 и 3, 3 и 4, 4 и N. Каждая пара - это кривая безье, нужно определить недостоющие опорные точки, первая и последняя известны и точно принадлежат общей кривой. Логика такова.

Comment: Про направления точек еще можете дать пояснения?

Comment: "Направления точек": я хотел сказать что если у вас однородная последовательность точек, то я не понимаю как построить по ним Безье. Если в каждой точек ещё добавить "скорость", то, да, можно. А так смотрите Катмул-Рома и Б-сплайны.

Comment: Какая "скорость"? Соль?

Comment: "Скорость" - направление движения. Дополнительные параметры для Безье.

Comment: Окай. Окай. Окай.